# RadGrid in design time loss all changes after rebind datasource

Tags: asp.net, webforms, telerik

When Telerik RadGrid detects changes in EntityDataSource during design time, an option to Rebind appears, but if accepted,  all my manual changes get lost (template columns dropped etc., a full refresh of the grid is automatically made).

My question:
**how prevent the above to happen and update only existing columns where the  changed properties are relevant and add new columns?**

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are referring to this message:
[image]

Once you click yes than all your manual modifications to the grid get lost.
I am not sure if a different method exist but what I do is very simple.

1) click **"No"**

2) open the wizard and add the new columns manually (Master Table View>>Columns>>add the column type you need.

3) Select the new added column and in the field **"DataField"**, write the name of the column in the database that you need to bound.

In this way the radgrid does not get refreshed and you can add new columns.
Let us know if this works for you.